# How can you type narrow this array of Results from neverthrow?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of `Results` from [neverthrow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neverthrow). I want to check if an error exists in any of them, and if so, exit my function. The problem is, when no errors exist, I want to destructure the array into the relevant `Ok` types as it's impossible for an `Err` to exist now.

Here's an example of the issue i'm facing:

```js
import { Err, ok, Result } from "neverthrow";

function resultIsError(
  result: Result<unknown, Error>
): result is Err<unknown, Error> {
  return result.isErr();
}

function doSomething() {
  const results = [
    ok(true) as Result<boolean, Error>,
    ok("foobar") as Result<string, Error>,
    ok({ foo: "bar" }) as Result<{ foo: string }, Error>
  ];

  const resultErrors = results.filter(resultIsError);

  if (resultErrors.length > 0) {
    return resultErrors;
  }

  const [someBool, someString, someObj] = results;

  const someBoolValue: boolean = someBool.value;
  const someStringValue: string = someString.value;
  const someObjValue: { foo: string } = someObj.value;
}
```

The issue is that when I try to access `.value` I get this error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Err<boolean, Error>'

Typescript isn't able to detect that `Err` isn't possible to exist now. Is there a clean, concise way to handle this?

I created this codesandbox to demonstrate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-architecture-nivu94?file=/src/index.ts:9-12

Answer (score 0):

I did create another example, trying to fix your issues at [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-tom-lu1ol4?file=/src/index.ts)

I will edit this answer to explain further more:

#### Issue

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Err<boolean, Error>'
```

#### Problems

in your example, you have this line

```
ok(true) as Result<boolean, Error>
```

this basically means assign type of method `ok()` to be `Result<boolean, Error>`. But in `neverthrow` types document type of `ok()` is `Ok<T, E>`

```
declare type Result<T, E> = Ok<T, E> | Err<T, E>;
declare const ok: <T, E = never>(value: T) => Ok<T, E>;
declare const err: <T = never, E = unknown>(err: E) => Err<T, E>;
```

You have this error because value of `ok(true) as Result<boolean, Error>` is Ok<boolean, Error> but its type is either  `Ok<boolean, Error> | Err<boolean, Error>`. So if in case, it's types of `Err<boolean, Error>` it will not have property `value`. this's `ts` try to tell us

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Err<boolean, Error>'
```

#### Solution

instead of using `Result<boolean, Error>` you could use `Ok<boolean, Error>`

```
ok(true) as Ok<boolean, Error>

// or
ok<boolean, Error>(true)  // using ts generic

// better
ok(true)
```

#### Answer

##### hardcode types of `result`

```
import { Err, ok, Ok, Result } from "neverthrow";

function resultIsError(
  result: Result<unknown, Error>
): result is Err<unknown, Error> {
  return result.isErr();
}

function doSomething() {
  const results: 
  [
   Ok<boolean, Error>,
   Ok<string, Error>,
   Ok<{ foo: string }, Error>
  ] = [
    ok(true),
    ok("foobar"),
    ok({ foo: "bar" })
  ];

  const resultErrors = results.filter(resultIsError);

  if (resultErrors.length > 0) {
    return resultErrors;
  }

  const [someBool, someString, someObj] = results;
  
  const someBoolValue = someBool.value;
  const someStringValue = someString.value;
  const someObjValue = someObj.value;

  console.log(someBoolValue, someStringValue, someObjValue);
}

doSomething()
```

##### use dynamic types of `result`

```
import { Err, ok, Result } from "neverthrow";

function resultIsError(
  result: Result<unknown, Error>
): result is Err<unknown, Error> {
  return result.isErr();
}

function doSomething() {
  const results = [ok(true), ok("foobar"), ok({ foo: "bar" })];

  const resultErrors = results.filter(resultIsError);

  if (resultErrors.length > 0) {
    return resultErrors;
  }

  const [someBool, someString, someObj] = results;

  const someBoolValue = someBool.value;
  const someStringValue = someString.value;
  const someObjValue = someObj.value;

  console.log(someBoolValue, someStringValue, someObjValue);
}

doSomething();
```

although `someBoolValue` will console as `boolean` in this case, its types is `string | boolean | { foo: string; }`

Comment: Replace the `Ok`'s in the tuple type with `Result`. Then you will get the errors that OP wants to fix. To be clear, changing the type of `results` is *not* how they want to solve it.

Comment: @caTS  to be clear, I don't think hardcode types of `results` is a good way either. i edit my answer to provide another solution.

Comment: I may need to update my question to be more clear. The reason I have it typed that way, is that my real world example is an array of Result, whereas the actual values should be Ok. My example was the simplest way to demonstrate the problem